# Best way to create custom modal dialog in angular2?

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular2-directives

I'm working in a team project where there is a component for modal dialog window, which is being placed everywhere that window is needed with `*ngIf`, a callback function passed to input, a message and some other stuff. I would like to create a directive, which would be placed on `<button>` or `<a>`, intercept the click event, show that modal dialog and if it's accepted then call the `(click)` handler of original element. What's the best way to do it? Atm I'm considering somehow removing that `(click)` handler by the directive and attaching that handler to it, inside of which I would programmatically create modal dialog with appropriate callback. Is my idea good or would you recommend something else?

Comment: Most implementations I have seen in ng1/ng1 create a service along with the modal component.  Developers simply dependency inject the service and call modal.show({...}) when they need it.

Comment: Please check ngx-bootstrap it is easy for modal in angular 2
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the "best" way, but ng-bootstrap has a modal component.

[NgModal in ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal)

See `NgbModalRef` is the reference to a modal window. You can use that to get information on the modal close, or change content etc.